# OpenCV in Android Studio

Tags: android, opencv, android-studio, gradle

I want to use OpenCV library in my app with Android Studio. I followed instructions found [here](http://blog.hig.no/gtl/2014/08/28/opencv-and-android-studio/) but I get error

> Configuration with name 'default' not found

What can be wrong?

I use Android Studio 1.0 with gradle 2.2.1.

Comment: Now we could import modules with Android studio and steps could be much simpler. Can you try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27356635/1180117

Comment: Thank you, it works. Write it as an answer then I can accept it.

Comment: @BartoszBialecki @Kiran   , I've followed it to step No.4 , I can't find the `native` directory under my `sdk ` directory.Am I missing something?

Comment: @RomanticElectron you have to add natvie directory from the sdk of the OpenCV library, not Android sdk.

Comment: You can find a working Android Studio project with OpenCV including native support (gradle-experimental:0.3.0) here: [https://github.com/leadrien/opencv_native_androidstudio](https://github.com/leadrien/opencv_native_androidstudio)

Answer (score 332, accepted):

The below steps for using Android OpenCV sdk in Android Studio.  This is a simplified version of [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22427267/1180117).

1. **Download** latest OpenCV sdk for Android from [OpenCV.org](http://opencv.org/releases.html)  and decompress the zip file.
2. **Import OpenCV to Android Studio**, From *File -> New -> Import Module*, choose *sdk/java* folder in the unzipped opencv archive.
3. **Update build.gradle** under imported OpenCV module to update 4 fields to match your project build.gradle a) compileSdkVersion b) buildToolsVersion c) minSdkVersion and d) targetSdkVersion.
4. **Add module dependency** by *Application -> Module Settings*, and select the *Dependencies* tab. Click *+* icon at bottom, choose *Module Dependency* and select the imported OpenCV module.

   - For Android Studio v1.2.2, to access to Module Settings :
     in the project view, right-click the dependent module
     -> *Open Module Settings*
5. **Copy *libs*** folder under *sdk/native* to Android Studio under *app/src/main*.
6. In Android Studio, **rename the copied *libs* directory to *jniLibs*** and we are done.

Step (6) is since Android studio expects native libs in `app/src/main/jniLibs` instead of older `libs` folder. For those new to Android OpenCV, don't miss below steps

- include `static{ System.loadLibrary("opencv_java"); }` (Note: for OpenCV version 3 at this step you should instead load the library `opencv_java3`.)
- For step(5), if you ignore any platform libs like x86, make sure your device/emulator is not on that platform.

OpenCV written is in C/C++. Java wrappers are

1. **[Android OpenCV SDK](http://opencv.org/platforms/)** - OpenCV.org maintained Android Java wrapper. I suggest this one.
2. **[OpenCV Java](http://opencv.org/opencv-java-api.html)** - OpenCV.org maintained auto generated desktop Java wrapper.
3. **[JavaCV](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv)** - Popular Java wrapper maintained by independent developer(s). Not Android specific. This library *might* get out of sync with OpenCV newer versions.

Comment: I am getting errors following the second step, Shall I delete the `javadocs` directory ?.It's also asking me for installing `android sdk 14` though I am targetting devices that support `android sdk 15`

Comment: @RomanticElectron Hope you have downloaded OpenCV4Android 2.4.10 from link https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-android/2.4.10/OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk.zip/download and not that java desktop version ?

Comment: I am using `OpenCV4Android 2.4.9` , I have completed step 4 but I am unable to find the `sdk/native` directory in my `sdk` directory.Am I missing something?

Comment: @RomanticElectron  I just re-downloaded that file and rechecked. `native` folder is present. Not sure why it is missing for you.

Comment: Ok I got it, I thought you were talking about the `sdk` installation directory on my system while you were talking about the directory which comes with `Android Open CV SDK`.Ok completed step 6. Where do I include `static{ System.loadLibrary("opencv_java"); }`?

Comment: @RomanticElectron where did you add include static{ System.loadLibrary("opencv_java"); } ??? In the activity ??

Comment: @AshokVarma No I didn't ,  it's not required

Comment: @RomanticElectron i done the process and i was able to import OpenCV. but i tried opencv.android.utils.matToBitmap it failed. Should i need to setup NDK also ??

Comment: @RomanticElectron where do you include static{ System.loadLibrary("opencv_java"); } ? You say "Thanks I've got it" but there seems to be no message in between. Then you say it's not needed. Could you explain a little more? Thanks.

Comment: @puntofisso It should be working fine without it ? Isn't it ? It was required in older versions perhaps , the newer work fine without it.

Comment: I've followed your instructions and when I've done third step I've tried to do fourth step, but I couldn't do anything on my module 'android' (It's sample ZXing app). So I've restarted Android Studio and instead of module 'android' there was openCV module, which is even more confusing. The old module is gone and I don't know what to do.

Comment: for anyone having the `android-14` error after importing the module in step 2, you need to manually edit the `build.gradle` in the openCV directory **in your project** as shown in step 3.

Comment: If you still have problem watch this video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JIHfqzTdOcQ)

Comment: why do we write `System.loadLibrary("opencv_java3")` while the *.so* file is named *libopencv_java3*?

Comment: where should the < static{ System.loadLibrary("opencv_java"); } > be included?

Comment: This works great. Note that if you are only planning to support certain architectures, you can copy only the libraries for them. In case a user with a different architecture tries to run the app, I think (not yet tested) the app will ask to install the OpenCV manager.

Comment: The only problem, though, is that your repository will grow with more than 1000 OpenCV files. It'd be great if we could just add a jar or something, instead of all the separate files.

Comment: Some links are broken. Please fixed broken the links. (This may help other users)

Comment: Although this method packages the jni libs into the APK, it does not help for native C/C++ coding as a ```externalNativeBuild``` or ```ndk``` block is not found in ```build.gradle``` file. Recent updates in Android Studio 2.3.0 has received that kind of integration. Please check my answer for more information: http://www.stackoverflow.com/a/43886764/2949966

Comment: note at step 5: copy the `sdk/native/libs` folder, not the `sdk/native` folder (the phrasing in the answer makes this easy to overlook)

Comment: If I want to write C++ code for OpenCV on Android Studio, should I do the steps you wrote above?

Comment: I can't understand this step `include static{ System.loadLibrary("opencv_java"); } ` where should I add this?

Comment: Also in this step `Update build.gradle under imported OpenCV module to update 4 fields to match your project build.gradle a) compileSdkVersion b) buildToolsVersion c) minSdkVersion and d) targetSdkVersio ` there is no numbers to change. I use android studio v2.3 and only have this line with numbers `        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
`

Comment: I think, Step#5 need be done under openCV module, not our "app" module.

Comment: while importing `/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/java` android studio not showing module name text box for edit, result module name import as `java`. After that in dependencies there no java module showing, even after successfully importing the module

Comment: As of OpenCV 4.6.0, you need to select `sdk` for the module directory, not `sdk/java`.

Comment: @kiranpradeep Where does the `static{}` block go?

Answer (score 147):

**Integrating OpenCV v3.1.0 into Android Studio v1.4.1**, instructions with additional detail and this-is-what-you-should-get type screenshots.

Most of the credit goes to Kiran, Kool, 1", and SteveLiles over at opencv.org for their explanations.  I'm adding this answer because I believe that Android Studio's interface is now stable enough to work with on this type of integration stuff.  Also I have to write these instructions anyway for our project.

Experienced A.S. developers will find some of this pedantic.  This answer is targeted at people with limited experience in Android Studio.

1. Create a new Android Studio project using the project wizard (Menu:/File/New Project):

   - Call it "*cvtest1*"
   - Form factor:  *API 19, Android 4.4 (KitKat)*
   - *Blank Activity* named *MainActivity*

     You should have a *cvtest1* directory where this project is stored.  (the title bar of Android studio shows you where cvtest1 is when you open the project)
2. Verify that your app runs correctly.  Try changing something like the "Hello World" text to confirm that the build/test cycle is OK for you.  (I'm testing with an emulator of an API 19 device).
3. Download the OpenCV package for Android v3.1.0 and unzip it in some temporary directory somewhere.  (Make sure it is the package specifically for Android and not just the OpenCV for Java package.)  I'll call this directory "*unzip-dir*"  Below *unzip-dir* you should have a *sdk/native/libs* directory with subdirectories that start with things like *arm*..., *mips*... and *x86*...  (one for each type of "architecture" Android runs on)
4. From Android Studio import OpenCV into your project as a module:
   Menu:*/File/New/Import_Module*:

   - Source-directory:  *{unzip-dir}/sdk/java*
   - Module name:  Android studio automatically fills in this field with *openCVLibrary310* (the exact name probably doesn't matter but we'll go with this).
   - Click on *next*.  You get a screen with three checkboxes and questions about jars, libraries and import options.  All three should be checked.  Click on *Finish.*

     Android Studio starts to import the module and you are shown an *import-summary.txt* file that has a list of what was not imported (mostly javadoc files) and other pieces of information. 
     [image]

     But you also get an error message saying *failed to find target with hash string 'android-14'...*.  This happens because the build.gradle file in the OpenCV zip file you downloaded says to compile using android API version 14,
     which by default you don't have with Android Studio v1.4.1.
     [image]
5. Open the project structure dialogue (*Menu:/File/Project_Structure*).  Select the "app" module, click on the *Dependencies* tab and add *:openCVLibrary310* as a Module Dependency.  When you select *Add/Module_Dependency* it should appear in the list of modules you can add.
   It will now show up as a dependency but you will get a few more *cannot-find-android-14* errors in the event log.
6. Look in the *build.gradle* file for your app module.  There are multiple build.gradle files in an Android project.  The one you want is in the *cvtest1/app* directory and from the project view it looks like *build.gradle (Module: app)*.  Note the values of these four fields:

   - compileSDKVersion  (mine says 23)
   - buildToolsVersion (mine says 23.0.2)
   - minSdkVersion (mine says 19)
   - targetSdkVersion (mine says 23)
7. Your project now has a *cvtest1/OpenCVLibrary310* directory but it is not visible from the project view:

[image]

Use some other tool, such as any file manager, and go to this directory.  You can also switch the project view from *Android* to *Project Files* and you can find this directory as shown in this screenshot:
[image]

Inside there is another *build.gradle* file (it's highlighted in the above screenshot).  Update this file with the four values from step 6.

8. Resynch your project and then clean/rebuild it.  (Menu:*/Build/Clean_Project*)  It should clean and build without errors 
   and you should see many references to *:openCVLibrary310* in the *0:Messages* screen.

   [image]

   At this point the module should appear in the project hierarchy as **openCVLibrary310**, just like **app**.  (Note that in that little drop-down menu I switched back from *Project View* to *Android View* ).  You should also see an additional *build.gradle* file under "Gradle Scripts" but I find the Android Studio interface a little bit glitchy and sometimes it does not do this right away.  So try resynching, cleaning, even restarting Android Studio.

   You should see the openCVLibrary310 module with all the OpenCV functions under java like in this screenshot:

   [image]
9. Copy the *{unzip-dir}/sdk/native/libs* directory (and everything under it) to your Android project, to *cvtest1/OpenCVLibrary310/src/main/*, and then rename your copy 
   from *libs* to *jniLibs*.  You should now have a *cvtest1/OpenCVLibrary310/src/main/jniLibs* directory.  Resynch your project and this directory should now
   appear in the project view under **openCVLibrary310**.

   [image]
10. Go to the onCreate method of *MainActivity.java* and append this code:

    ```
    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "  OpenCVLoader.initDebug(), not working.");
    } else {
        Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "  OpenCVLoader.initDebug(), working.");
    }
    ```

    Then run your application.  You should see lines like this in the Android Monitor:
    [image]
    (I don't know why that line with the error message is there)
11. Now try to actually use some openCV code.  In the example below I copied a .jpg file to the cache directory of the cvtest1 application on the android emulator.  The code below loads this image, runs the canny edge detection algorithm and then writes the results back to a .png file in the same directory.

    Put this code just below the code from the previous step and alter it to match your own files/directories.

    ```
    String inputFileName="simm_01";
    String inputExtension = "jpg";
    String inputDir = getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();  // use the cache directory for i/o
    String outputDir = getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
    String outputExtension = "png";
    String inputFilePath = inputDir + File.separator + inputFileName + "." + inputExtension;


    Log.d (this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "loading " + inputFilePath + "...");
    Mat image = Imgcodecs.imread(inputFilePath);  
    Log.d (this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "width of " + inputFileName + ": " + image.width());
    // if width is 0 then it did not read your image.


    // for the canny edge detection algorithm, play with these to see different results
    int threshold1 = 70;
    int threshold2 = 100;

    Mat im_canny = new Mat();  // you have to initialize output image before giving it to the Canny method
    Imgproc.Canny(image, im_canny, threshold1, threshold2);
    String cannyFilename = outputDir + File.separator + inputFileName + "_canny-" + threshold1 + "-" + threshold2 + "." + outputExtension;
    Log.d (this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Writing " + cannyFilename);
    Imgcodecs.imwrite(cannyFilename, im_canny);
    ```
12. Run your application.  Your emulator should create a black and white "edge" image.  You can use the Android Device Monitor 
    to retrieve the output or write an activity to show it.

The **Gotchas**:

- If you lower your target platform below KitKat some of the OpenCV libraries will no longer function, specifically the classes related to *org.opencv.android.Camera2Renderer* and other related classes.  You can probably get around this by simply removing the apprpriate OpenCV .java files.
- If you raise your target platform to Lollipop or above my example of loading a file might not work because use of absolute file paths is frowned upon.  So you might have to change the example to load a file from the gallery or somewhere else.  There are numerous examples floating around.

Comment: 16-Feb edit:  jniLibs now in the openCVLibrary310 directory, not the main app directory.  Either works but it seems cleaner to me to keep them in the opencv part.  Plus *more* screenshots and the "Gotchas" part.

Comment: I think some import statements are missing, otherwise very good job! +1

Comment: I don't mind revising it.  Please tell me what to add.

Comment: I followed your answer but failed. **1**i got the error `OpenCV error: Cannot load info library for OpenCV` **2** `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/www.deven.com.opencv-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libopencv_java3.so` What these error about i done step by step as  you written.

Comment: @DevendraSingh I got the same error as you got but I realised I had missed step 9.

Comment: This answer might be a good addition to the "Documentation Beta".  I looked at the opencv topic, but I couldn't tell how or what to do there.  Seems to me we need separate topics: opencv general, opencv android, etc.

Comment: Great answer.Specially by adding liberaries into app. Only missing thing is about adding android camera permission

Comment: Although this method packages the jni libs into the APK, it does not help for native C/C++ coding as a ```externalNativeBuild``` or ```ndk``` block is not found in ```build.gradle``` file. Recent updates in Android Studio 2.3.0 has received that kind of integration. Please check my answer for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43886764/2949966

Comment: Anyone able to fix the "cannot load info" error? I know the library loads anyway!

Comment: what if we want to code in c++ for opencv on android studio?

Comment: @ssimm i'm really in need of help with this question, can you help me, please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61216402/how-to-improve-image-segmentation-using-the-watershed

Answer (score 40):

For everyone who felt they want to run away with all the steps and screen shots on the (great!) above answers, this worked for me with `android studio 2.2.1`:

1. Create a new project, name it as you want and take the default (minSdkVersion 15 is fine).
2. Download the zip file from here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-android/  (I downloaded 3.2.0 version, but there may be a newer versions).
3. Unzip the zip file, the best place is in your workspace folder, but it not really matter.
4. Inside `Android Studio`, click `File->New-> Import Module` and navigate to `\path_to_your_unzipped_file\OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk\java` and hit Ok, then accept all default dialogs.
5. In the `gradle` file of your `app`  module, add this to the dependencies block:

   ```
    dependencies {
        compile project(':openCVLibraryXYZ')
        //rest of code
    }
   ```

Where XYZ is the exact version you downloaded, for example in my case:

```
    dependencies {
        compile project(':openCVLibrary320')
        //rest of code
    }
```

Comment: Nice and simple, thnx ;-) Works also for the version 3.2.0.

Comment: Thank you, it's indeed the easier solution. One point from me. The new OpenCV module couldn't be compiled. The answer here helped me to fix this issue http://stackoverflow.com/a/40302788/408780

Comment: just to add to what @blacharnia said, just make sure you use 'compile project(':openCVLibrary320')' in the cradle dependencies section instead of 310

Comment: @yshahak or can someone help me in this matter, I really need to do this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61876457/image-segmentation-using-segment-seeds-watershed-in-android

Answer (score 14):

**Android Studio 3.4 + OpenCV 4.1**

1. Download the latest OpenCV zip file from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-android/) (current newest version is 4.1.0) and unzip it in your workspace or in another folder.
2. Create new Android Studio project normally. Click `File->New->Import Module`, navigate to `/path_to_unzipped_files/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/java`, set Module name as `opencv`, click `Next` and uncheck all options in the screen.
3. Enable `Project` file view mode (default mode is `Android`). In the `opencv/build.gradle` file change `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` to `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` and replace `application ID "org.opencv"` with

   ```
   minSdkVersion 21
   targetSdkVersion 28
   ```

   (according the values in `app/build.gradle`). Sync project with Gradle files.
4. Add this string to the dependencies block in the `app/build.gradle` file

   ```
   dependencies {
       ...
       implementation project(path: ':opencv')
       ...
   }
   ```
5. Select again `Android` file view mode. Right click on `app` module and goto `New->Folder->JNI Folder`. Select change folder location and set `src/main/jniLibs/`.
6. Select again `Project` file view mode and copy all folders from `/path_to_unzipped_files/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/libs` to `app/src/main/jniLibs`.
7. Again in `Android` file view mode right click on `app` module and choose `Link C++ Project with Gradle`. Select Build System `ndk-build` and path to `OpenCV.mk` file `/path_to_unzipped_files/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk`.

   `path_to_unzipped_files` must not contain any spaces, or you will get error!

To check OpenCV initialization add Toast message in MainActivity `onCreate()` method:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(OpenCVLoader.initDebug()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

If initialization is successful you will see `true` in Toast message else you will see `false`.

Comment: Above you say " replace application ID "org.opencv" with ....." but there is nothing following the "with".  Can you please clarify?  Do you mean to say "remove the applicationId entry and add two entries as follows:"

Comment: @Dale Yes, you should replace `application ID "org.opencv"` string with two strings: `minSdkVersion 21` and
`targetSdkVersion 28` (according the values in app/build.gradle file)

Comment: I followed all the steps as you described . But getting error
E/art: dlopen("/data/app/com.example.objectsegmentation-1/lib/arm64/libopencv_java4.so", RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: library "libc++_shared.so" not found

Answer (score 5):

In your build.gradle

```
repositories {
  jcenter()
}

implementation 'com.quickbirdstudios:opencv:4.1.0'
```

[More information](https://github.com/quickbirdstudios/opencv-android)

Comment: How can we use it in C++?

Answer (score 3):

```
Download
```

Get the latest pre-built OpenCV for Android release from https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases and unpack it (for example, opencv-4.4.0-android-sdk.zip).

Create an empty Android Studio project

```
Open Android Studio. Start a new project.
```

[image]

Keep default target settings.

Use "Empty Activity" template. Name activity as MainActivity with a corresponding layout activity_main.
Plug in your device and run the project. It should be installed and launched successfully before we'll go next.

```
 Add OpenCV dependency
```

Go to File->New->Import module

and provide a path to unpacked_OpenCV_package/sdk/java. The name of module detects automatically. Disable all features that Android Studio will suggest you on the next window.

[image]

[image]

Configure your library build.gradle (openCVLibrary build.gradle)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

Implement the library to the project (application build.gradle)

```
 implementation project(':openCVLibrary330')
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me and was as easy as adding a gradle dependancy:

https://bintray.com/seesaa/maven/opencv#

https://github.com/seesaa/opencv-android

The one caveat being that I had to use a hardware debugging device as arm emulators were running too slow for me (as AVD Manager says they will), and, as described at the repo README, this version does not include x86 or x86_64 support.

It seems to build and the suggested test:

```
static {
    OpenCVLoader.initDebug();
}
```

spits out a bunch of output that looks about right to me.

Comment: This was from a fresh project in android studio. I did not import anything, did not download anything, etc. Just add the gradle dependency and sync.

Answer (score 2):

On the latest openCV version 4.5.2, you need to import the whole sdk folder, not sdk/java, other wise when you go to add the dependency, OpenCV doesn't show up. full description here:

[Cant add openCV module as a dependency to my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67593334/android-studio-add-module-dependency-doesnt-see-my-module/67593518#67593518)

Answer (score 1):

It took me a long time to figure out how it works.
The method I used does not require **Gradle**.

**Disclaimer:** I do not know how good or bad this method is. So use it on your own.

1. Download Both "**OpenCV4Android**" and "**AndroidNDK**" (*Download NDK to found libc++_shared.so as I say later*)
2. Extract "OpenCV4Android" somewhere and import one of the examples like this one "**opencv-4.5.1-android-sdk\OpenCV-android-sdk\samples\tutorial-1-camerapreview**" to android studio.
3. After importing, go to "OpenCV4Android" sdk again "**OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk\java\src\org\opencv**" and copy this folder with all subfolders to your "tutorial-1-camerapreview" sample project like section (**1**) of this image:

[image]

4. Now you need **JNI Libraries** and also **libc++_shared.so**. Make a folder in your sample project and name it "**Libs**"(*this name is not important but you have to configure it later*). Go to "OpenCV4Android" sdk again and copy all folders of "**opencv-4.5.1-android-sdk\OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk\native\libs**" to your new "**libs**" folder in your sample project as section (**2**) of above picture. Also extract ndk and go to this address "**android-ndk\android-ndk-r20b\sources\cxx-stl\llvm-libc++\libs**" and copy **libc++_shared.so** to your libs directory.

*Note that for both libraries you must place at least four files with the same name but in folders for different CPU architectures.*

5. Important part. You must load these libs somewhere. I put them in Activity. Check section (**3**) of above image.

```
    static {
            System.loadLibrary("opencv_java4");
    }
```

6. For last step open "Project Structure" and define your Libs folder like this image:

[image]

And for last TIP make an APK directly if you don't want to emulate your application.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install opencv 3.4.15 on Android studio Arctic Fox with just 3 steps:

- step 0: create a new empty project
- step 1: Download opencv-3.4.15 from the [official release page](https://opencv.org/releases/). Extract it to your place of choice
- step 2: Add the following 3 lines to the bottom of your settings.gradle

```
def opencvsdk='/path/to/opencv-3.4.1-android-sdk/OpenCV-android-sdk'
include ':opencv'
project(':opencv').projectDir = new File(opencvsdk + '/sdk')
```

Hit `Sync Now`

- step 3: Add the below 2 lines to your **app/build.gradle dependencies**

```
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation project(':opencv')
```

Hit `Sync Now`

Done !!!

Verification:

Add the below lines to your **MainActivity.java**

```
static {
    String TAG = "MainActivity";
    if (OpenCVLoader.initDebug()){
        Log.i(TAG, "opencv installed successfully");
    }else{
        Log.i(TAG, "opencv not installed");
    }
}
```

Source:

After you have extracted the zip file, go to the location below:

**opencv-3.4.1-android-sdk/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk** and open **build.gradle** file with any text viewer. There if you scroll down you will find something similar to the screenshot below

[image: opencv-android-installation]

Answer (score 1):

In the latest OpenCV releases you need to import the whole `sdk` folder.

Actually, it is pretty easy to import OpenCV by just following the official guide from its `build.gradle` file. Here is a slightly edited version:

1. Add the following to `settings.gradle` (`sdk` directory of OpenCV should be a subdirectory of the specified path):

```groovy
def opencvsdk='<path_to_opencv_android_sdk_rootdir>'
include ':opencv'
project(':opencv').projectDir = new File(opencvsdk + '/sdk')
```

2. Add dependency into `app/build.gradle`:

```groovy
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation project(':opencv')
}
```

3. Load OpenCV native library: use `System.loadLibrary("opencv_java4")` (the actual name depends on your OpenCV version) or `OpenCVLoader.initDebug()`
4. (Optional) For native C++ support (necessary to use OpenCV in native code of application):

- In `app/CMakeLists.txt`:

```cmake
find_package(OpenCV <your-opencv-version> REQUIRED java)
...
target_link_libraries(<your-native-lib-name> ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})
```

- In `app/build.gradle`:

```groovy
defaultConfig {
       ...
       externalNativeBuild {
           cmake {
               cppFlags "-std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions"
               arguments "-DOpenCV_DIR=" + opencvsdk + "/sdk/native/jni",
                       "-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=TRUE"
           }
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am bit late. But I was also unable to load the latest version (v:4.5.5) of opencv sdk in android studio, because everyone was saying that ***File-> New-> Import Module->*** then go to ***opencv-4.5.5-android-sdk\OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk\java*** folder, but when I imported, it seems to be nothing in my imported opencv module so after a long research I was able to find solution so here I have shared.

1. Download Opencv sdk from official website:
   Go to : https://opencv.org/releases/,
   Click on ***Android***. I have downloaded 4.5.5 version.
2. In your project click on ***File > New > Import Module...*** and select the ***opencv-4.5.5-android-sdk/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk*** directory inside your OpenCV download. Rename to opencv_v455 or if you want to leave it (up to you) and wait for the Gradle to finish. The directory you selected should have been copied in the root of your project where the default ***/app*** directory exists.
3. Open the Project Structure by clicking on ***File > Project Structure***, then go to ***Dependencies*** (on the left), click on ***app*** and on the ***+ icon*** in the ***Declared Dependencies*** tab (not the one in the ***Modules*** tab).
4. Now click on ***Module Dependency*** and select the checkbox for the ***OpenCV SDK*** that you imported earlier. You should now see it in the list with the other dependencies, so click on ***Apply*** and ***OK*** to exit from the ***Project Structure***;
5. Open the ***build.gradle*** file of your ***app*** module, copy the values of ***compileSdkVersion***, ***minSdkVersion*** and ***targetSdkVersion***, then paste them in the ***build.gradle*** file of the ***OpenCV*** module replacing the default ones so they match exactly. You can also update the ***sourceCompatibility*** and ***targetCompatibility*** fields to ***JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8*** in ***compileoptions*** tag in ***app*** module.
6. Now click on ***Sync Now*** and wait for gradle to finish.

If you want to check that you have successfully added opencv. you can write below code in MainActivity.kt or MainActivity.java.

```
if (OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
    Log.d("myTag", "OpenCV loaded")
}
```

**Cheers!!**

Answer (score 0):

Anybody facing problemn while creating jniLibs cpp is shown ..just add ndk ..

Answer (score 0):

Just add jcenter() to repositories in build gradle

```
repositories {
            jcenter()
             google()
             mavenCentral()
            }
```

then add this implementation

```
implementation 'com.quickbirdstudios:opencv:4.1.0'
```