# How to import openCV samples into Android Studio

Tags: android, opencv, android-studio

Just as the title says. I tried "Import Project" then selected this file:

C:...\OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk\samples\tutorial-1-camerapreview

Then selected this folder as the location for the full copy of the project:

C:...\AndroidStudioProjects\tutorial-1-camerapreview4

I then get the following warnings:

- Project OpenCV Tutorial 1 - Camera Preview:C:\Users\Michael\OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk\samples\tutorial-1-camerapreview\project.properties:
  Library reference ....\sdk\java could not be found
  Path is C:\Users\Michael\OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk\samples\tutorial-1-camerapreview....\sdk\java which resolves to C:\Users\Michael\OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk\sdk\java

Can anyone help please? searches for answers so far have not been fruitful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the existing project where you have configured to include OpenCV module, use "Import Module" to import opencv samples.

Comment: Thanks, I am currently trying to statically initialize opencv. I created a new project. Imported the opencv module and the sample module. 

I then added the following code at the start of my Activity class:

static {
    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        // Handle
    }
}

I then added the following after "super.onResume":

mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);

And then deleted this:
OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_3, this, mLoaderCallback); 

I then get the following error:
OpenCV error: Cannot load info library for OpenCV

Comment: So, the "Import Module" answer works for you? If so, please accept the answer.

Comment: For your other problem in your comment, I recommend you to read this [link](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#application-development-with-static-initialization) to setup properly the statical initialization of OpenCV for your project.

Comment: Sorry, I've accepted it now. Yes I have been trying to follow that but those instructions seem to be written for eclipse and I don't know how to do it in android studio. I am stuck on stage 2:
"select Project -> Properties -> Android -> Library -> Add select OpenCV Library - 2.4.9;"... I can't find a "Project" or "project properties" button anywhere.

Comment: IMHO, if you already used "Import Module" to import OpenCV4Android in Android Studio, you can skip the step 1&2 and go directly to step 3.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. The next step says:

If your application project doesn’t have a JNI part, just copy the corresponding OpenCV native libs from <OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk>/sdk/native/libs/<target_arch> to your project directory to folder libs/<target_arch>.

How do I know if my app has a JNI part? I googled it and it says it is just an interface that allows java to be called by native applications written in other languages.

Comment: You may try the answer of this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406303/opencv-in-android-studio)

Comment: I've followed this link already but I am getting:

"OpenCV manager was not found, would you like to install it?"

when I try to run the program...
I have so far used import project to import the openCvtutorial1preview, then used "import module" to import the opencv library. I then let gradle re-build. I then went through "my computer >...> OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk > sdk > native > libs" and copied the 4 folders within into my project under "src>main>libs" & renamed it jnilibs.

Comment: I checked the dependencies under "Project Structure > openCVTutorialCameraPreview > Dependencies" and "openCVLibrary2410" is already listed there.

I then copy and pasted this:
static {
    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        // Handle initialization error
    }
}
into Tutorial1Activity under the variable declarations

Comment: For the message "OpenCV manager was not found, would you like to install it?", please select yes/install.

Comment: For your other question about native dependencies, please post as a new question and describe it properly. The help may come hopefully.

Comment: I solved it in the end, a few days of fiddling around worked out. Thanks for all of your help!