# OpenCV with Android Studio

Tags: android, opencv, gradle

For use OpenCV in my app with Android Studio I complete the [following instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406303/opencv-in-android-studio) to Step 6. But I don't know how and where include

`static { System.loadLibrary("opencv_java"); }`

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In main activity, like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2{

    static {
        if(!OpenCVLoader.initDebug())
            Log.d(sLog, "OpenCv load fail!");
        else
            Log.d(sLog, "OpenCv succes.");
    }

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
       ...
   }

    ...
}
```

instead of using System.loadLibrary(...), you can use OpenCVLoader.initDebug() which is suggested by OpenCv