# OpenCV Android SDK not working

Tags: android, opencv

So I developed an Android App that uses the OpenCV Android SDK. I managed to import everything thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406303/opencv-in-android-studio), but when I run the app in my phone, I get the following message:
"Package not found: OpenCV3 Manager package was not found! Try to install it?"

If I click "yes", I get a "not found" page in google play.

In the OpenCV Android SDK, there is a folder called "apk" with opencv manager apks for different architectures. But which one is for my phone? I have an xperia Z2 which has a snapdragon processor.

Besides, I'd like to make my app standalone. Is it possible with openCV? 
I am pretty confused with the horrible documentation for the Android integration of this lib. Could someone please guide me in the process?

Comment: Please try my answer. Screenshots included!
http://stackoverflow.com/a/35135495/5611377

Answer (score 1):

It looks like OpenCV 3 Manager is not yet available on Google Play and requires a manual install:

http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/ChangeLog

You can install the manager onto your device using the adb tool (from the directory where you've unzipped the sdk):

```
adb install OpenCV-3.0.0-rc1-android-sdk/apk/OpenCV_3.0.0-rc1_Manager_3.00_armv7a-neon-android8.apk
```

I was able to run the samples on my android (5.0.2) phone after that!