# Unable to import OpenCVLoader

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

Unable to import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;

I'm new to Opencv.I was trying to load opencv libraries.

but I was unable to import "org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader"

anything I need to download from SDK manager

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What have you done till now? Are you using AndroidStudio or Eclipse for development?

Comment: i am using android studio

Comment: @FabinPaul 
i have downloaded OpenCV for android
and copied java folder to my project

Comment: check out this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406303/opencv-in-android-studio)