# failed to import org.opencv.features2d.DMatch; in android studio

Tags: opencv, android

i'm using [imageComparator](https://github.com/torcellite/imageComparator) to compare two images with OpenCV library but i can't import DMatch class in my app `org.opencv.features2d.DMatch` any one knows how should i fix this problem ?

Comment: did you added the entire ImageComparator lib to your project?

Comment: @DanielNetzer yeah all of it,the problem is from OpenCV library

Comment: do you have a log of some sort? a code you can share to ease things up abit for us yo try and help you better?

Comment: on what ADT are you working on?

Comment: @DanielNetzer i'm working with Android Studio,DMatch class is gone from my OpenCV library that's why it gave's me error.i think they've remove it in the new version of the library

Comment: how do you add OpenCV libs in the gradle?

Comment: @DanielNetzer you should import it from "import module" in FILES>IMPORT MODULE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well finally I've found my answer by my self :D

if you guys have this problem too u should download OpenCV library version 2.4.9

**EDIT**

if you are using newer versions the package name is changed to `core`

Comment: then dont mark it as an answer, but what lib version did you used? and why not try and implement the latest version of opencv?

Comment: @DanielNetzer i was using the last version but in that version DMatch class is removed so you can't use imageComparator but in the old versions (2.4.9) you can find DMatch...

Comment: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=DMatch According to github testcode for OpenCV latest version DMatch is still a valid class. but if that works, it works.

Answer (score 8):

I got the [imageComparator](https://github.com/torcellite/imageComparator) project working in Android Studio with [openCV 3.1](http://opencv.org/downloads.html) by following this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27421494/546054)

and to fix the **`failed to import` error** replace:

```
import org.opencv.features2d.DMatch;
```

with

```
import org.opencv.core.DMatch;
```

Answer (score 3):

so after a quick research you are right implementing OpenCV with Android Studio requires a few steps to actually get it working properly.

**Adding OpenCV to your new project**

- Create a folder called “libraries” inside your Android Studio
  project, and copy there entire content of sdk/java out of your OpenCV
  Android folder.
- Rename that folder to “opencv”, so that you will end up having your       Android Studio project with subfolder “libraries/opencv”.
- Now, inside this “opencv” folder, create a build.gradle file, with the following content:

  apply plugin: 'android-library'

  buildscript {
    repositories {
      mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
  }

  android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

  defaultConfig {
      minSdkVersion 8
      targetSdkVersion 23
      versionCode 3000
      versionName "3.0.0"
    }

  sourceSets {
      main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        }
      }
    }

** Weird bug Code tag change indentation on the code.

- Edit your settings.gradle file in your application’s main directory and add this line:

  include ':libraries:opencv'
- Open Android Studio
- Do this in Android Studio: Tools/Android/Sync Project with Grade files
  Go to File/Project Structure, inside Modules pick your ‘app’, then from the Tab pick: Dependencies, click + to add new dependency, pick Module Dependency, and add :library:opencv dependency to your project. Click OK.
- Create a jniLibs folder in the /app/src/main/ location and copy the all the folder with *.so files (armeabi, armeabi-v7a, mips, x86) in the jniLibs from the OpenCV Android SDK/native/libs folder.
- Make sure that you do have Android SDK 19 installed (as per above gradle files), or use a version that you have installed.
- Try to sync Gradle again, after adding the dependency.  You may need to delete section “android” from your top-level build.gradle if the sync complains.
- Build the project.

Source :: https://blog.hig.no/gtl/2015/10/01/android-studio-opencv/

EDIT 1:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTw_GIQNbD8 - Youtube video with all the steps required to do from scratch by Md. Zakir Hossen.

Comment: @PHELAT if this answer helped you I would appreciate you marking it as an answer.

Comment: well thank you for your answer but this is not my answer i have imported this library successful