# Cannot resolve symbol error when importing OpenCv4Android in Android Studio

Tags: android, opencv, android-studio, cannot-find-symbol

I want to use `OpenCV4Android` in Android Studio. I downloaded **OpenCV for Android** from this link: 
http://opencv.org/downloads.html

But, when I try to import it, I get different errors in Camera2Renderer.java like, `Cannot resolve symbol 'camera2'`, `Cannot resolve symbol 'CameraDevice'`, `Cannot resolve symbol 'Size'`, and `Cannot resolve symbol 'CaptureRequest'`.

I have tried both methods available here:

[OpenCV in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406303/opencv-in-android-studio)

http://answers.opencv.org/question/14546/how-to-work-with-opencv4android-in-android-studio/

But, I get the same error.

Can anyone please tell me how to solve this error to be able to use openCV?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue while configuring OpenCV SDK with Android Studio.

I am using the latest SDK build of OpenCV : OpenCV-3.1.0-android-sdk

Please ensure that you have configured your build.gradle scripts.

Build.gradle(Module: app) -->

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.dev.opencvapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
  }
sourceSets { main { jni.srcDirs = ['src/main/jni', 'src/main/jniLib/'] } }
}

 dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
  compile project(':openCVLibrary310')
  }
```

Build.gradle(Module: openCVLibrary310) -->

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 24
  buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 21
  }

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
      }
  }
}
```

After doing this you should be able to build the app with out any errors.

I hope I helped you!!

Comment: I tried this one and fix the same problem I encountered.