# How to import openCV 3.1 in android studio 1.5

Tags: android, opencv

AOA,

How do I import OpenCv 3.1 in android studio 1.5? I'm following [these steps]( 
[OpenCV in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406303/opencv-in-android-studio)).  I've completed 6 steps, but don't know where to include this line of code in
step 6:

```
( include static{ System.loadLibrary("opencv_java"); }
```

I've included this line in MainActivity, but am still unable to import any OpenCv statement e.g. import org.opencv etc as in snapshot..
Also I didn't download any wrapper e.g. Android OpenCv SDK, JavaCv or OpenCv java as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406303/opencv-in-android-studio) link, I thought only downloading "OpenCv for android " is enough.

Please guide me how to fix these errors and if I need any wrapper for it, then give me proper download link. 
thankyou

[Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpBIF.png)

Answer (score -1):

You may try to follow instructions [here](https://blog.hig.no/gtl/2015/10/01/android-studio-opencv/)
It helped me on my android studio 1.5.1 and opencv 3.1.0 library.