# Android studio + OpenCV + FFmpeg

Tags: java, android, opencv, ffmpeg, opencv3.0

I have problem with code, which is functional only for Genymotion device (Android 4.1.1), but for Genymotion device 5.0.1 and real device Huawei honor 4c Android 4.4.2 not.

I have imported OpenCV 3.1 to Android studio by: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27421494/4244605
I added JavaCV with FFmpeg by: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv

Android studio 1.5.1
minSdkVersion 15
compileSdkVersion 23

Code is only for test.
**OpenCVCameraActivity.java:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SubMenu;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.Frame;
import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

@SuppressWarnings("ALL")
public class OpenCVCameraActivity extends Activity implements
        CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2,
        View.OnTouchListener {

    //name of activity, for DEBUGGING
    private static final String TAG = OpenCVCameraActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private OpenCVCameraPreview mOpenCvCameraView;
    private List<Camera.Size> mResolutionList;
    private MenuItem[] mEffectMenuItems;
    private SubMenu mColorEffectsMenu;
    private MenuItem[] mResolutionMenuItems;
    private SubMenu mResolutionMenu;

    private static long frameCounter = 0;

    long startTime = 0;
    private Mat edgesMat;
    boolean recording = false;
    private int sampleAudioRateInHz = 44100;
    private int imageWidth = 1920;
    private int imageHeight = 1080;
    private int frameRate = 30;
    private Frame yuvImage = null;
    private File ffmpeg_link;
    private FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder;

    /* audio data getting thread */
    private AudioRecord audioRecord;
    private AudioRecordRunnable audioRecordRunnable;
    private Thread audioThread;
    volatile boolean runAudioThread = true;
    ShortBuffer[] samples;


    private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
                case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                    Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                    mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
                    mOpenCvCameraView.setOnTouchListener(OpenCVCameraActivity.this);
                break;
                default:
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(Static.DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "onCreate()");

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        try {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_opencv);

            mOpenCvCameraView = (OpenCVCameraPreview) findViewById(R.id.openCVCameraPreview);
            mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
            mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);

            //mOpenCvCameraView.enableFpsMeter();

            ffmpeg_link = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "stream.mp4");
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        if (Static.DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "onRestart()");
        super.onRestart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        if (Static.DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "onStart()");
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        if (Static.DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "onResume()");
        super.onResume();

        if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Internal OpenCV library not found. Using OpenCV Manager for initialization");
            OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_11, this, mLoaderCallback);
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV library found inside package. Using it!");
            mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (Static.DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "onCreateOptionsMenu()");
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        List<String> effects = mOpenCvCameraView.getEffectList();

        if (effects == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Color effects are not supported by device!");
            return true;
        }

        mColorEffectsMenu = menu.addSubMenu("Color Effect");
        mEffectMenuItems = new MenuItem[effects.size()];

        int idx = 0;
        ListIterator<String> effectItr = effects.listIterator();
        while(effectItr.hasNext()) {
            String element = effectItr.next();
            mEffectMenuItems[idx] = mColorEffectsMenu.add(1, idx, Menu.NONE, element);
            idx++;
        }

        mResolutionMenu = menu.addSubMenu("Resolution");
        mResolutionList = mOpenCvCameraView.getResolutionList();
        mResolutionMenuItems = new MenuItem[mResolutionList.size()];

        ListIterator<Camera.Size> resolutionItr = mResolutionList.listIterator();
        idx = 0;
        while(resolutionItr.hasNext()) {
            Camera.Size element = resolutionItr.next();
            mResolutionMenuItems[idx] = mResolutionMenu.add(2, idx, Menu.NONE,
                    Integer.valueOf(element.width).toString() + "x" + Integer.valueOf(element.height).toString());
            idx++;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (Static.DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "onPause()");
        super.onPause();

        if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if (Static.DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "onStop()");
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (Static.DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy()");
        super.onDestroy();

        if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
    }

    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

        ++frameCounter;
        //Log.i(TAG, "Frame number: "+frameCounter);

        return inputFrame.rgba();
    }


    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
        edgesMat = new Mat();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStopped() {
        if (edgesMat != null)
            edgesMat.release();

        edgesMat = null;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.i(TAG, "called onOptionsItemSelected; selected item: " + item);
        if (item.getGroupId() == 1)
        {
            mOpenCvCameraView.setEffect((String) item.getTitle());
            Toast.makeText(this, mOpenCvCameraView.getEffect(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (item.getGroupId() == 2) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            Camera.Size resolution = mResolutionList.get(id);
            mOpenCvCameraView.setResolution(resolution);
            resolution = mOpenCvCameraView.getResolution();
            String caption = Integer.valueOf(resolution.width).toString() + "x" + Integer.valueOf(resolution.height).toString();
            Toast.makeText(this, caption, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.i(TAG,"onTouch event");
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss");
        String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
        String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +
                "/sample_picture_" + currentDateandTime + ".jpg";
        mOpenCvCameraView.takePicture(fileName);
        Toast.makeText(this, fileName + " saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Click to ImageButton to start recording.
     */
    public void onClickBtnStartRecord2(View v) {
        if (Static.DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "onClickBtnStartRecord()");

        if(!recording)
            startRecording();
        else
            stopRecording();
    }

    private void startRecording() {
        if (Static.DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "startRecording()");
        initRecorder();

        try {
            recorder.start();
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            recording = true;
            audioThread.start();
        } catch(FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        if (Static.DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "stopRecording()");

        runAudioThread = false;
        try {
            audioThread.join();
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        audioRecordRunnable = null;
        audioThread = null;

        if(recorder != null && recording) {

            recording = false;
            Log.v(TAG, "Finishing recording, calling stop and release on recorder");
            try {
                recorder.stop();
                recorder.release();
            } catch(FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            recorder = null;
        }
    }


    //---------------------------------------
    // initialize ffmpeg_recorder
    //---------------------------------------
    private void initRecorder() {

        Log.w(TAG, "init recorder");
        try {

            if (yuvImage == null) {
                yuvImage = new Frame(imageWidth, imageHeight, Frame.DEPTH_UBYTE, 2);
                Log.i(TAG, "create yuvImage");
            }

            Log.i(TAG, "ffmpeg_url: " + ffmpeg_link.getAbsolutePath());
            Log.i(TAG, "ffmpeg_url: " + ffmpeg_link.exists());
            recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(ffmpeg_link, imageWidth, imageHeight, 1);
            recorder.setFormat("mp4");
            recorder.setSampleRate(sampleAudioRateInHz);
            // Set in the surface changed method
            recorder.setFrameRate(frameRate);

            Log.i(TAG, "recorder initialize success");

            audioRecordRunnable = new AudioRecordRunnable();
            audioThread = new Thread(audioRecordRunnable);
            runAudioThread = true;
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //---------------------------------------------
    // audio thread, gets and encodes audio data
    //---------------------------------------------
    class AudioRecordRunnable implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);

            // Audio
            int bufferSize;
            ShortBuffer audioData;
            int bufferReadResult;

            bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleAudioRateInHz,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
            audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, sampleAudioRateInHz,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize);

            audioData = ShortBuffer.allocate(bufferSize);

            Log.d(TAG, "audioRecord.startRecording()");
            audioRecord.startRecording();

            /* ffmpeg_audio encoding loop */
            while(runAudioThread) {
                //Log.v(TAG,"recording? " + recording);
                bufferReadResult = audioRecord.read(audioData.array(), 0, audioData.capacity());
                audioData.limit(bufferReadResult);
                if(bufferReadResult > 0) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "bufferReadResult: " + bufferReadResult);
                    // If "recording" isn't true when start this thread, it never get's set according to this if statement...!!!
                    // Why?  Good question...
                    if(recording) {
                            try {
                                recorder.recordSamples(audioData);
                                //Log.v(TAG,"recording " + 1024*i + " to " + 1024*i+1024);
                            } catch(FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception e) {
                                Log.v(TAG, e.getMessage());
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
            Log.v(TAG, "AudioThread Finished, release audioRecord");

            /* encoding finish, release recorder */
            if(audioRecord != null) {
                audioRecord.stop();
                audioRecord.release();
                audioRecord = null;
                Log.v(TAG, "audioRecord released");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**OpenCVCameraPreview.java:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;

import org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.List;

public class OpenCVCameraPreview extends JavaCameraView implements Camera.PictureCallback {

    private static final String TAG =  OpenCVCameraPreview.class.getSimpleName();
    private String mPictureFileName;

    public OpenCVCameraPreview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public List<String> getEffectList() {
        return mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedColorEffects();
    }

    public boolean isEffectSupported() {
        return (mCamera.getParameters().getColorEffect() != null);
    }

    public String getEffect() {
        return mCamera.getParameters().getColorEffect();
    }

    public void setEffect(String effect) {
        Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
        params.setColorEffect(effect);
        mCamera.setParameters(params);
    }

    public List<Camera.Size> getResolutionList() {
        return mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    }

    public void setResolution(Camera.Size resolution) {
        disconnectCamera();
        mMaxHeight = resolution.height;
        mMaxWidth = resolution.width;
        connectCamera(getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

    public Camera.Size getResolution() {
        return mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
    }

    public void takePicture(final String fileName) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Taking picture");
        this.mPictureFileName = fileName;
        // Postview and jpeg are sent in the same buffers if the queue is not empty when performing a capture.
        // Clear up buffers to avoid mCamera.takePicture to be stuck because of a memory issue
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);

        // PictureCallback is implemented by the current class
        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Saving a bitmap to file");
        // The camera preview was automatically stopped. Start it again.
        mCamera.startPreview();
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(this);

        // Write the image in a file (in jpeg format)
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mPictureFileName);

            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();

        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            Log.e("PictureDemo", "Exception in photoCallback", e);
        }

    }
}
```

**Gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "co.example.example"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets/opencv/pom.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets/opencv/pom.xml'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets/ffmpeg/pom.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets/ffmpeg/pom.xml'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'

    compile group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv', version: '1.1'
    compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version: '3.0.0-1.1', classifier: 'android-arm'
    compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version: '3.0.0-1.1', classifier: 'android-x86'
    compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'ffmpeg', version: '2.8.1-1.1', classifier: 'android-arm'
    compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'ffmpeg', version: '2.8.1-1.1', classifier: 'android-x86'

    compile project(':openCVLibrary310')
}
```

**proguard-rules.pro**
Edited by: [link](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/wiki/Configuring-Proguard-for-JavaCV)

**jniLibs:**
app/src/main/jniLibs:

```
armeabi armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a mips mips64 x86 x86_64
```

**Problem**

```
02-19 11:57:37.684 1759-1759/ I/OpenCVCameraActivity: onClickBtnStartRecord()
02-19 11:57:37.684 1759-1759/ I/OpenCVCameraActivity: startRecording()
02-19 11:57:37.684 1759-1759/ W/OpenCVCameraActivity: init recorder
02-19 11:57:37.691 1759-1759/ I/OpenCVCameraActivity: create yuvImage
02-19 11:57:37.691 1759-1759/ I/OpenCVCameraActivity: ffmpeg_url: /storage/emulated/0/stream.mp4
02-19 11:57:37.696 1759-1759/ I/OpenCVCameraActivity: ffmpeg_url: false
02-19 11:57:37.837 1759-1759/ W/linker: libjniavutil.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x18cc3
02-19 11:57:37.837 1759-1759/ W/linker: libjniavutil.so: unused DT entry: type 0x6ffffffe arg 0x21c30
02-19 11:57:37.837 1759-1759/ W/linker: libjniavutil.so: unused DT entry: type 0x6fffffff arg 0x1
02-19 11:57:37.838 1759-1759/co.example.example E/art: dlopen("/data/app/co.example.example-2/lib/x86/libjniavutil.so", RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "av_version_info" referenced by "libjniavutil.so"...
02-19 11:57:37.843 1759-1759/co.example.example I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil>
02-19 11:57:37.844 1759-1759/co.example.example E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                        Process: co.example.example, PID: 1759
                                        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
                                            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4020)
                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015)
                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
                                         Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil
                                            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309)
                                            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:413)
                                            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:381)
                                            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.avcodec$AVPacket.<clinit>(avcodec.java:1650)
                                            at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder.<init>(FFmpegFrameRecorder.java:149)
                                            at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder.<init>(FFmpegFrameRecorder.java:129)
                                            at co.example.example.OpenCVCameraActivity.initRecorder(OpenCVCameraActivity.java:320)
                                            at co.example.example.OpenCVCameraActivity.startRecording(OpenCVCameraActivity.java:266)
                                            at co.example.example.OpenCVCameraActivity.onClickBtnStartRecord2(OpenCVCameraActivity.java:259)
                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015) 
                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**
When i edit dependencies in the Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile project(':openCVLibrary310')
    compile files('libs/ffmpeg.jar')
    compile files('libs/javacpp.jar')
    compile files('libs/javacv.jar')
    compile files('libs/ffmpeg-android-arm.jar')
    compile files('libs/ffmpeg-android-x86.jar')
}
```

App throws exceptions:

```
Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lorg/bytedeco/javacpp/avutil;
Exception Ljava/lang/NoClassDefFoundError; thrown while initializing Lorg/bytedeco/javacpp/avcodec$AVPacket;
```

---

**Solution:**
Remove `ffmpeg-android-arm.jar` and `ffmpeg-android-x86.jar` from Gradle.

For `arm` architecture in my case i extract all `*.so` files from `lib` folder from `ffmpeg-android-arm.jar` to `app/src/main/jniLibs` to `armeabi` and `armeabi-v7a` folders.

For `x86` architecture in my case i extract all `*.so` files from `lib` folder from `ffmpeg-android-x86.jar` to `app/src/main/jniLibs` to `x86` folder.

So i can remove `exclude 'META-INF...` from `packagingOptions` from Gradle.
Not need to make edit about `proguard-rules.pro`.

Note about virtual devices:
Solution not working for Genymotion, but for Google virtual device yes.

**Final Gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "co.example.example"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
    compile files('libs/ffmpeg.jar')
    compile files('libs/javacpp.jar')
    compile files('libs/javacv.jar')
    compile project(':openCVLibrary310')
}
```