# Error: package android.hardware.camera2 does not exist OpenCV

Tags: opencv, android

I'm trying to add the OpenCV module to a project, but I'm not able to solve some gradle issues. Here is my `app.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sveder.cardboardpassthrough"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile files('libs/cardboard.jar')
    compile project(':openCVLibrary')
}
```

Here's the `build.gradle` file of the OpenCV (3.0) module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 21
}

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, my app and OpenCV gradle files match, and yet whenever I try to build the project I have the error `error: package android.hardware.camera2` does not exist. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Change `compileSdkVersion 17` to minimum 21 (recommended latest). Because `android.hardware.camera2` was [added in API 21](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html).

Comment: The phone I'm developing with has an API version of 17...does this mean I have to switch to an older version of OpenCV? Is there no "compatiability" mode that allows me to revert to the old Camera API?

Comment: You are already targeting ` minSdkVersion 8`, so it would work on 17.

Comment: The problem is, it doesn't. It still complains about missing camera2 even though it should be defaulting to the older Camera API.

Comment: No, I am saying. change `compileSdkVersion` to 23, then also it would work on 17 because minSdkVersion is 8. `camera2` can't be imported because it was added in 21.

Comment: That did it! Thanks!!

Answer (score 33):

Apart from build.gradle . Check settings in the Project Structure `Ctrl +Alt+Shift+s` . This solved my problem.
[image]

Comment: Thank you. That helped. The only thing, I had to press F4 to open module settings. Only then I could see the same picture :)

Comment: Thank you this one helped. This should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to change the sdkversion as Rohit said, but the problem was there. But then I realized that I need to change the sdkversion for the OpenCV library. So press Shift+Ctrl+Alt+s, get to the properties tab of OpenCV library. Change the sdkVersion to 21 or later.[Here is the screenshot, in case if you are confused with tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pf3qe.png)