# Android Studio OpenCV Library not working

Tags: android, opencv

I have followed the  directions here [OpenCV in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406303/opencv-in-android-studio)  the one that has 94 votes. I get this error when I dod System.loadlibrary("opencv-java")

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file     
  "/data/app/com.krikorherlopian.opencvsample-  
   1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=
   [/data/app/com.krikorherlopian.opencvsample-1/lib/arm, 
  /data/app/com.krikorherlopian.opencvsample-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-
  v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libopencv_java.so"                                                                                    
  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:367)                                                                                   
  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)                                                                                   
 at com.krikorherlopian.opencvsample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)                                                                                    
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)                                                                                  
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107                                                                                    
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)                                                                                    
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)                                                                                   
 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)                                                                                    
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)                                                                                    
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)                                                                                    
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)                                                                                  
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)                                                                                    
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                                   
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)                                                                                    
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

EDIT: I still get the error , and I have the ndk added . Krikors-MacBook-Air:~ KrikorHerlopian$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/KrikorHerlopian/Downloads/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/ndk-bundle
Whats the problem?

Edit2: Now I got problem of Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: /Users/KrikorHerlopian/Downloads/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/ndk-bundle//jni/Android.mk  when i try running my app from the terminal using /Users/KrikorHerlopian/Downloads/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build

Comment: libopencv_java.so is not found your must run your code with ndk in order to built in

Comment: how do i run my code on ndk? i downloaed the ndk.

Comment: you can run the your code from terminal in android stuidon

Comment: how? any tutorials? I downlaoded the ndk, but still get the error. I would like to know  how can i run my app.

Comment: please check my edited comment.

Comment: go tho android studio terminal than <Your ndk location>\ndk-build it will build ur project

Comment: check edited comment 2.