# Image Processing with opencv in android app

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am making an Android app which uses **OpenCV** and **Tessract** for ImageProcessing.
I installed all the nescessary components for both of them.

But I stuck at one Point.I am getting Runtime error :

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.opencv.core.Mat

but this class is Present in my app.[image]

How to solve this issue???

Comment: maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787571/use-opencv-mat-in-android-java-application-noclassdeffound-error-with-opencv-ma

Comment: thanks..but no use..