# What exactly does developing OpenCV4Android form trunk mean?

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-studio

I want to use opencv in android i am using android studio.  i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406303/opencv-in-android-studio)  answer then i integrate opencv with android studio but in other opencv official website i found other method of integration of opencv in android it says Building OpenCV4Android from trunk. My question is

1) what is does Building OpenCV4Android from trunk mean and what is the difference between Building OpenCV4Android from trunk and directly integrating opencv into android?

2) I think Building OpenCV4Android from trunk means building opencv apps using native c/c++ libraries. If my asumption is right how can i do it in android studio all the tutorials are in eclipse if not can we build opencv android app using c++ in android studio? i am saying here directly using c++ not java wrapper or opencv for java.

Answer (score 0):

The `trunk` is the latest commit in the core repository. The phrase is from SVN, in git the concept is called `master` and you find OpenCV's master here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/commits/master.

Building from trunk just means to build the very latest code yourself (as supposed to use previously defined versions which have been built for your convenience, e.g. [OpenCV 3.1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-android/3.1.0/OpenCV-3.1.0-android-sdk.zip/download). Such a download is called a "prebuilt version"

I would highly recommend to go for the prebuilts since they save you a lot of work and usually are better tested

Comment: thanks for your reply. Is it possible to build image processing android app using c++ opencv library in android studio.