# Use OpenCV for Create Face Lock Screen

Tags: android, opencv, android-studio

1 - I looked for face recognition similar to Create Face Lock Screen App. It is possible with use OpenCV ?

2 - I will be grateful if you would help me to use OpenCV in Android Studio .

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, opencv is capable for such task, and it works with Android.
2. You can start from the opencv4android page. Try setup the developing environment and run some sample codes. https://opencv.org/android/

For opencv with android studio, it was asked previously [OpenCV in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406303/opencv-in-android-studio)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.