# OpenCV static initialization in android studio

Tags: opencv, android-studio, static-libraries, android

I want to use static opencv in my android application.
To this end, I try to apply this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTw_GIQNbD8

My problem is that I can't paste the /opencv/sdk/java/ into /libs/ directory in my android application. This error message apprears:

[image]

Can you help me please? I use android studio 2.1.2 and opencv-2.4.9.

Comment: Nothing helpful can be said without analysing the code.

Comment: It is just a copy/past of the directory..

Comment: You can follow this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406303/opencv-in-android-studio)

Comment: Thank you for your help :) I tried the solution mentioned in the link but the initialization of openCV is failed and the screen in the mobile device is black when I run the application ( the camera does not open).

Comment: Please share the logcat error you are facing ?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the article about OpenCV in Android project so if you want check it out. I hope it'll help! This is the link [OpenCV in Android Project](https://blog.zaven.co/opencv-in-android-studio-project/)

Comment: Relevant bit: 

static {
       if (OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
           Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV initialize success");
       } else {
           Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV initialize failed");
       }
}

Answer (score 0):

I always copy to the project directory. See my picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYJaZ.png)