# Opencv samples not working in Android Studio

Tags: opencv, android

I installed Android Studio 3.1.4 and downloaded OpenCV-2.4.11-android-sdk. For first steps, I tried to run a sample that comes with the OpenCV SDK, e.g. face-detection. When I build the project in Android Studio I get the message:

> Error: Your project contains C++ files but it is not using a supported
>   native build system. Consider using CMake or ndk-build integration.
>   For more information, go to: 
>   https://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/add-native-code.html

On this site its said NDK, CMake and LLDB must be installed. But it already is.

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Its worth noting that OpenCV is not supported in any of the examples or documentation on Android studio - it is still clips based. Getting OpenCV to work in Studio with NDK is an ever changing problem - there are discussions here are elsewhere on this that are worth reading, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/40948953/334402 , but I have never found an 'easy' answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the C++ code, and the Makefiles in the project directory, in which case, you simply have to link Gradle to the native library:

1. In your project pane, **right-click** on your module, and select **Link C++ 
   Project with Gradle.**
2. From the **drop-down** select either **CMake** or **ndk-build**, depending on your project

   a. If you selected **CMake**, specify the **CMakeLists.txt** script in your project

   b. If you selected **ndk-build**, specify the **Android.mk**.

PS: **Android.mk** is located in; app/build/intermediates/ndk/debug.

Comment: Thank you. But how can I know if I need CMake or ndk-build? Its a sample project out of the opencv sdk.  And where is the CMakeLists.txt is located?

Comment: use ndk-build. You can refer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39589427/difference-between-cmake-and-ndk-build-in-android-studio-project

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was missing the location of the **ndk** in my **local.properties** file. Please add ndk path with android sdk in the **local.properties**

```
ndk.dir=/Path to the Sdk/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle
sdk.dir=/Path to the Ndk directory/Android/sdk
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not work. Now I created a new project. Then:

1. I clicked File->New->Import Module and added the java folder from my OpenCV-android-sdk.
2. File->Project Structure->app->Dependencies-> + module Dependency. I added openCVLibrary2411
3. Right click on app: New->folder->JNI Folder->change Folder location: I changed into "src/main/jniLibs/
4. I copied the contend of "OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk\native\libs" (4 folders: armeabi, armeabi-v7a, mips, x86) into "src/main/jniLibs/"
5. Right click on Packages: openCVLibrary2411->Link C++ Project with Gradle: Build System: ndk-build, Projekt Path: "[MyFolder]\OpencvTest7\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug"
6. In MainActivity.java I added after

> setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>
> if(OpenCVLoader.initDebug()){
>
> ```
>         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "opencv loaded successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>     }else
>     {
>         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "could not load opencv .", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>     }
> ```

When I run the Project I get the Toast ""could not load opencv .".

Comment: It might be better to add this as an update to your question, rather than as an answer.