# Updating openCV for Android

Tags: android, opencv, android-studio-2.2

I am developing an app that uses **openCV 2.4.11** and I would like to change the openCV library to **3.0+ version**. So that it works on 64bits devices, but i have no idea how to do this? i'm using **Android Studio 2.2.**

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the only solution i found to this problem was to create an all new project add opencv according to this thread: [OpenCV in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406303/opencv-in-android-studio) and then move all the files from my project to the new project.