# OpenCV and JNI setup in Android Studio

Tags: android, opencv, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I want to use OpenCV library in both my Java codes and JNI C++ codes in Android Studio.

How can I import OpenCV library and set up the NDK environment (JNI) in the same android project in **Android Studio**?

I could successfully do either one, but could not do both in a project even though I have tried many times.

I followed these two tutorials to set up the environment.
 1. [OpenCV for android](https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&persist_app=1&v=JIHfqzTdOcQ)
 2.[JNI/NDK](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-studio-jni/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0)
Does anyone have any idea why my setup was failed?
Or can anyone provide me a guide to set up the environment?

Comment: You haven't described _in what way_ your attempts failed, so we can't possibly know what you have done wrong.

Comment: Oh, how I hate coding tutorials as videos.  Hard to see, terrible music, waste of time...  There is a proper, albeit short, write-up [here](https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/03/setup-opencv-sdk-android-studio.html)

Comment: this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406303/opencv-in-android-studio?noredirect=1&lq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406303/opencv-in-android-studio?noredirect=1&lq=1) may help you