# How can I port this project to Android Studio?

Tags: opencv, android-studio

I am completely new to Android development. Can someone please provide me steps that how can I run this code via Android Studio?
https://github.com/quangpropk/TrafficSignsDetection

Comment: Does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406303/opencv-in-android-studio

Answer (score 1):

*Unzip the github project to a folder. 
Open Android Studio. Go to File->Import Project. 
Then choose the specific project you want to import and then click Next->Finish. It will build the Gradle automatically and'll be ready for you to use.*

OR

You can directly import github projects into Android Studio. File -> New -> Project from Version Control -> GitHub. Then enter your github username and password.Select the repository and hit clone.

The github repo will be created as a new project in android studio.