# Native OpenCV with async initialization (OpenCV Manager) in Android Studio (cmake)

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, opencv, cmake

My question is related to this: [OpenCV in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406303/opencv-in-android-studio)

Kiran's answer seems to be working fine for me and I also made it work with an application with native C++ parts (using cmake).

One thing I couldn't get to work yet is to make an app with native C++ parts with async initialization (through OpenCV Manager). Async initialization works fine for Java-only project and native app works fine with static initialization, but native app with async init seems to be more tricky. The native parts won't compile if I don't include the OpenCV libs (*.so/*.a) to the project - which would defeat the purpose of the async initialization. I suppose the solution should be in the OpenCV.mk file and I should just translate that to cmake. I probably should make some further additions in the CMakeLists.txt file (possibly something with linker flags), I just couldn't yet figure out what exactly. Did anyone figure this out yet?