# Unable to create OpenCV Objects

Tags: android, opencv

I am using Android Studio 3.0 and Gradle 3.0.0 and OpenCV 3.3.1.
Followed the below steps:

1.Imported OpenCv module (selecting the java folder within the OpenCV android sdk)

2.Added OpenCVLibrary331 as module dependency

3.Synced the build.gradle(app) with build.gradle(OpenCV) for the parameters:-
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 25

4.Copied the contents of libs folder of OpenCV android sdk/native under app/src/main/jniLibs of the android project

5.Installed npm

6.Copy pasted the Android.mk auto generated from the build from app/build/intermediates/ndk to under app/Android.mk such that it is in the same level of build.gradle(module level)
7.In the build.gradle(module) have included the ndk block

The project build without any error however unable to create any of the Open CV object. Any guidance to solve this issue??

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ibm.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        //added from saikat
       // sourceSets.main {
           // jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/jnilibs'
           // jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
       // }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { jni.srcDirs = ['src/main/jni', 'src/main/jniLibs/'] } }

    externalNativeBuild {
        // Encapsulates your CMake build configurations.
        // For ndk-build, instead use the ndkBuild block.
        ndkBuild {
            // Specifies a path to your CMake build script that's
            // relative to the build.gradle file.
            path "Android.mk"
        }
    }

}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':openCVLibrary331')
}
```

Comment: show your codes to we can help you.

Comment: Kindly let me know if this would suffice?

Comment: Try to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27421494/6950238) steps carefully.