# how to build and install opencv+contrib .so libraries for android

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

I'm trying to use the opencv contrib modules in android. I compiled the project and got the jar file, which I imported on my android project.
The problem is that when I try to instantiate the LBPHFaceRecognizer with the line `LBPHFaceRecognizer.create()` the program crashes and error says

> No implementation found for long
>   org.opencv.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer.create_0

Googling I found that I hadn't built the .so for the opencv_contrib modules. Following the idea from [this blog](http://tzutalin.blogspot.com.tr/2016/01/installing-opencv-310-and-contrib-lib.html) I built all the modules using `make -j4`, and in the `lib` folder I got many .so files including `libopencv_java340.so` and `libopencv_face.so` (the one I need) and many more.

Which one should I add to the ndk build path? At the moment I have the configuration as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406303/opencv-in-android-studio). And the one I built is for `armeabi-v7a`, same as what my phone supports, but still says the same thing.

Anyone has been able to add opencv contrib modules in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using

> org.bytedeco:javacv:1.3.2

. If you still want to answer this question I don't know.