# Cannot find opencv2 in Android Studio

Tags: android, c++, opencv, makefile, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to write a C++ file in Android Studio and I would like to use OpenCV in my project.

However, when I try to use the following includes, I get an error saying `Cannot Find 'opencv2'`.

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d.hpp>
```

To set up OpenCV in Android, you have to take the following steps, [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27421494/4601149), to use the Java part of OpenCV in Android Studio.

To the best of my knowledge to use the C++ part of OpenCV in Android Studio, you have to add `Android.mk` and `Application.mk` to the folder containing your native code.

My `Android.mk` file looks like the following.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

CVROOT := C:/Users/Dan/Documents/Repos/Android-Studio/Assets/opencv-3.4.1-android-sdk/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED
include $(CVROOT)/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE    := app
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native-lib.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

My `Application.mk` file looks like the following.

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-27
```

Am I doing something wrong to set my project up to use the C++ part of OpenCV on Android?

---

**Additional Information for if it makes a difference**

My project outline looks like this.

[image]

My gradles look like the following

*app module*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.test.esra"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    // Room - Managing local databases
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0'
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"
    //Jetbrains Annotations
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
    implementation project(':openCVLibrary341')
}
```

*openCVLibrary341 module*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 27
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

*project build.gradle*

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone else who arrives here with the same issue, the problem is fairly easy to fix.

You no longer need the `.mk` files so they can be deleted.

If you are starting a project from scratch, make sure you have Android NDK and CMake installed as well as enabling them for your project.

After following the initial steps posted in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27421494/4601149) to set up the Java part of OpenCV on Android. You will need to change your `app module's` build gradle to reflect the snippet below.

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
            abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'mips', 'mips64'
        }
    }
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']
    }
}
```

Then you want to edit the file `CMakeLists.txt`. In this file you want to include the following code underneath the `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION X.X.X)` line.

Also, you will need to add `lib_opencv` to the `target_link_libraries` near the bottom of `CMakeLists.txt`. This will help prevent undefined reference errors.

```
include_directories(your-path-to/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include)
add_library( lib_opencv SHARED IMPORTED )
set_target_properties(lib_opencv PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_java3.so)

...

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                   native-lib

                   # OpenCV lib
                   lib_opencv

                   # Links the target library to the log library
                   # included in the NDK.
                   ${log-lib} )
```

Make sure to replace `your-path-to` with your actual path to OpenCV for Android.

Finally, clean your project and refresh your linked C++ projects. This will remove the error.

I got this information from this really nice [GitHub page](https://github.com/leadrien/opencv_native_androidstudio). Credits to leadrien

---

Clarification on *You no longer need the `.mk` files*. This is true for Android Studio 3. I have not tested this on older versions of Android Studio or Eclipse, so you might need `.mk` files for those IDEs.