# Is there any way to import OpenCV in a monkeyrunner project?

Tags: android, python, opencv, monkeyrunner

Well i am running some python scripts to test several features on my android app and I am using the monkeyrunner tool and everything works great. But to test some features, I need to use the OpenCV module which I can't import in monkeyrunner. Is there any way to import this library?

```
import cv2
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   ImportError: No module named cv2

Comment: You can import openCV directly in android! I think is hard to import directly in monkeyrunner

Comment: And how can I do that?

Comment: This so thread refers to your question. I think this is the best way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406303/opencv-in-android-studio#27421494 
As advance i can tell to you to use the split abi in gradle when you compile a signed apk. Using split abi reduces the dimension of your compiled apk from ~90 MB to ~10 MB.

Comment: You should be able to use OpenCV with [AndroidViewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient)