# OpenCV Module name not seen when selected OpenCV sdk java

Tags: android-studio, opencv, android

I am trying to import OpenCV module in Android Studio but when I select the Java SDK from the downloaded OpenCV Android Java SDK folder, then in the Android Studio I don't see the OpenCV Module name below the file selection. Please refer below image:

[image]

I am using Android Studio Intellij Version: "4.0"
OpenCV Version "opencv-4.2.0-android-sdk"

I am using below links for reference:
[OpenCV in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406303/opencv-in-android-studio)