# Showing no OpenCV module in dependancies in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, opencv

I tried many tutorials and blogs for **Setting up OpenCV Android Library on Android Studio**
some of them are here

[A Beginner’s Guide to Setting up OpenCV Android Library on Android Studio](https://android.jlelse.eu/a-beginners-guide-to-setting-up-opencv-android-library-on-android-studio-19794e220f3c)

[Add OpenCV library into Android Studio](https://medium.com/@linjunghsuan/add-opencv-library-into-android-studio-6b02bc2920c0)

[OpenCV in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406303/opencv-in-android-studio)

but i am unable to configure it according to above solutions

at start when i try to import module from `/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/java` android studio not showing module name edit box and hence i have to add "java" as a `OpenCV` module name

[image]

OK after importing module with the name of java we have to add dependencies but in **add module dependencies** not showing any module name java or anything

[image]

Guys anyone know how can i resolve this issue or any proper steps for `OpenCV` configuration in `Android studio`

I am using

Android Studio -4.0

opencv-4.3.0-android-sdk

Answer (score 3):

First Screenshot: Android Studio may have removed that option in new version.

Second Screenshot: You can solve issue by editing build.gradle of Opencv as below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        //applicationId "org.opencv"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

Change **apply plugin: 'com.android.application'** to **apply plugin: 'com.android.library'**

and comment out the following line :

**applicationId "org.opencv"**

Comment: But when running the apk I am getting "Package not found"