# Getting error in importing the opencv module in android studio

Tags: android, opencv

I'm new to android development,

[image]

I am trying to configure opencv in my project but the default path is not showing what should I do?

it is not showing next or finish option??
anyone can guide me about it ?

Comment: Hello :) check out this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/66692717/2227070

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenCV in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406303/opencv-in-android-studio)